# How to typehint a callable with arbitrary argument list (vararg)

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I am trying to typehint a function that looks like this:

```py
def delete_file_if_exists():
    """Fixture providing a function that deletes a list of files of given filename it it exists
    """
    def deletion_function(*args: AnyPath) -> None:
        """A function deleting the file of given path if it exists
        :param args:The list of path to delete if file exists
        """
        for arg in args:
            if os.path.isfile(arg):
                os.remove(arg)
    return deletion_function
```

And I wonder how to exactly type it:

1.

```py
def delete_file_if_exists() -> Callable[..., None]:
```

works but does not specify the type of variable arguments

2.

```py
def delete_file_if_exists() -> Callable[[List[AnyPath]], None]:
```

does not work but a [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) run on it gives the following exception :
`Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[VarArg(Union[str, bytes, _PathLike[str], _PathLike[bytes]])], None]", expected "Callable[[List[Union[str, bytes, _PathLike[str], _PathLike[bytes]]]], None]")`

So I am wondering if I could do something with this VarArg (that I can not manage to import) or if I am stuck with an elipsis typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the type VarArg with [mypy-extension](https://pypi.org/project/mypy-extensions/#files).

Comment: `def delete_file_if_exists() -> Callable[[VarArg(AnyPath)], None]` (with `from mypy_extensions import VarArg`) turned out to be proper solution indeed